# how can we can get the size of progress dialog box with timer in android

Tags: android

I am using Progress Dialog box.By default it open on full screen so can i resize it.

please let me know the answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the Documentation ([ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)) I can't find any method to change the size of this dialog.

I think you have 2 options, you could extend the `ProgressDialog` class, or create a custom dialog. More information about dialogs in Android are here: [Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)